# MySQL select query to return only numeric data from mixed string WITHOUT using REGEXP_REPLACE?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which includes a varchar field containing strings of mixed data.
I want a select query to return every row; but, only the numeric portion of the stored string.

For example:
100
101C
102D
103xx
104
105VV

should return:
100
101
102
103
104
105

I can easily select rows containing only numeric data with REGEXP; but, i need every row, not just those having numbers only.
I believe I could use REGEXP_REPLACE; but, this old legacy MySQL 5.0 server does NOT have the REGEXP_REPLACE function. Upgrading this old server isn't an option.
I could do nested REPLACE() statements if I new every possible option; but, that isn't practical.

Short of exporting the raw data out of the system, fixing it and putting it back, is there another option within this legacy version of MySQL?

Comment: It appears I may be able to simply CAST() the value as an unsigned integer; although, I am unsure if there might be any unknown limitations to this method.

Comment: cast will discard anything after the first non-digit

Answer (score 0):

Not going to be the most efficient thing in the world, but you can split it into characters and select only the digits and rejoin them (as long as you have a primary key or some unique key to group by to join them):

```
select id,group_concat(substr(bar,position,1) order by position separator '') as bar
from (select 1 position union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 ... union all select 256) position
cross join foo
where substr(bar,position,1) in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,' ')
group by id;
```